# Adding character before text in Excel without using formula

Tags: excel, format

I want to add a prefix before a text without using formula, without linking to another cell.
So that I can directly type in the text in a single cell but showing with a prefix.
Something similar to ("new" #) in the custom format if using number.
Possible to achieve using custom format only?

I've tried to use "new" # in custom but this is only applicable for numbers. Typing in text will return the text that I've typed.

I expected to type "book" but the cell should show as "new book".

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
"new" @
```

as a custom format.